# is there any limit to print the values on console in eclipse indigo or any other IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse, console

I recently came across the problem of printing 4219 lines on console. but when excuted the program i saw that only half of the lines were printed. when i used debug mechanism i found that all the values are coming and getting printed on the console.

so is there a limit for the console to print the values if so how to make it to print all.

thanks

Antony

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with console properties:

[image]

Comment: But in eclipse, buffer size must be between 1000 and 1000000 inclusive

Comment: may be now it is 800000 before it was 80000

Answer (score 4):

This is usually a setting for the console program. Open eclipse properties and search for console.

Answer (score 4):

You need to increase the Console buffer size.

For Eclipse it is here: Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Console -> you should see entry for buffer size.

So i guess you have something similar. Just increase the number.

Comment: There is a checkbox for unlimited.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Window/Preferences/
then choose
Run/Debug/Console

and take a look on "Console buffer size". I typically increase this number. Do the same.