# How to remove charcter console limit from Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a little problem with Eclipse. I want to get all output from console but I can see only a part of error. I have tried to remove charter limit from settings but it doesn't work. Someone can help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is there any limit to print the values on console in eclipse indigo or any other IDE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632340/is-there-any-limit-to-print-the-values-on-console-in-eclipse-indigo-or-any-other)

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse, Window >> Preferences >> Run/Debug > Console there's a checkbox "Limit console output" and a textfield for entering the buffer size of the console.

Uncheck that check box or provide 1000000 i.e 1MB in the textfield.

I think it will solve your problem.

Comment: i have reinstalled eclipse. thanks you, now it work!